# JavaFX 2 TreeView Styling - lines from parents to children

Tags: treeview, javafx-2

I have a pretty big structure of data, which I want to show in the TreeView.
When a lot of branches and sub-branches are opened, it's not clear what belongs to what.

Is there a way (CSS?) how to style the TreeView, so it will be showing the lines from parents to children like in Swing?

[image: desired result - example from Swing]

Thank you for any ideas...

Comment: do you have any ideas yourself

Comment: actually no, I was looking for something in CSS definitions or in the settings of the TreeView component, found nothing to start with... :-/

Comment: so not strictly css? if so i have something

Comment: Any solution is welcome :-)

Comment: Any success so far? I'm also interested to find the solution to this question, and I see that there is nothing yet. After three years I think I can ask if you have founded something.