# Why do tree-view-like controls in newer GUI Frameworks like WPF/JavaFX lack hierarchical lines?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, javafx

Tree-view-like controls used to have lines in old GUI frameworks like Win32, but in newer GUI systems like WPF or JavaFX that use 3D-acceleration like DirectX or OpenGL lack those lines. Maybe I am the weird one, but I hate tree views that have no lines. There is an [existing question about adding lines to JavaFX TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297616/javafx-2-treeview-styling-lines-from-parents-to-children) but it has no answers and only comments from other people who want the lines.

So, the question is, is it a coincidence that both WPF/JavaFX have no hierarchical lines for tree view or similar controls? Or is this some kind of inherent limitation of 3D-acclerated GUI?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is clearly a design choice. The guide lines are meant to visualize the hierarchy. But they are somehow ugly and redundant as the hierarchy is already visualized by the indention. So it's just modern design style to go without those lines. It definitely has nothing to do with hardware limitations etc. (hardware today has become  more powerful by the way - so this can't be the reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that 3rd party control vendors like Telerik and others have tree line support. The native WPF TreeView doesn't. Here are a couple reasons why:

**DESIGN**

WPF was created at a time where UI design was trying to get away from the old battleship gray Win32/MFC/WinForms styling. Many tree controls of that time went for a cleaner look without the lines.

**TECHNICAL**

Due to WPF's template/rendering model, calculating and displaying lines can hinder performance with very large trees. It's also more complex to implement, especially with UI virtualization. Microsoft has never put much work into creating robust or high-performance data controls, so this has been an opportunity for third party control vendors to address.

Comment: _"Microsoft has never put much work into creating robust or high-performance data controls"_. Very bold statement. You won't see this lines in any modern UI library, no matter if desktop or web application. They are too noisy and of no use. This lines are really easy to implement using a `Border` around the `ItemsPresenter`. That's why the WPF controls are performing very well - they only provide a very basic layout and are very easy to extend. Much better than fat heavy controls, that can do everything but you never need it. Complex controls with tons of switches to enable/disable features.

Comment: I build high-end 3D CAD applications, so I have a lot of experience with this. Engineers looking at the 3D data in a massive model in a tree need the lines to keep track of everything. Not all users are the same.

Comment: If Microsoft did not put lines because it causes performance problems when there are many items, those third-party's TreeView-like controls don't have the same problem? Does that mean that there is a way to implement lines without causing such issues even when there are many items, but Microsoft was too lazy to do that and just removed that feature?

Comment: I wouldn't say that Microsoft was lazy. Most likely it wasn't a design goal for them initially when they created the TreeView. However with WPF their direction was always to defer to third parties for more advanced controls.